# Identify the current Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to identify the Navigation Bar in the current view so that I can add a subview to it.

I have seen this code which is able to identify the Navigation Bar that has been dynamically created and tagged:

```
UINavigationBar *theNavigationBar = (UINavigationBar *)[inParent.view viewWithTag:kNavigationBarTag];
```

But in my case the Navigation bar is not being created dynamically, so it's not tagged. Is there a way to identify it otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar
```

Only valid when called from a method in a UIViewController, of course. Otherwise, try to retrieve a reference to the view controller and take it from there.

Comment: Is there a way to add a right button using that reference: self.navigationController.navigationBar (add a right button)...

Answer (score 1):

You set the `tag` property for `UINavigationBar` if you create or access it from your `UIViewController` (`self.navigationController.navigationBar` )

because `tag` is the property of `UIView` which is the super class for `UINavigationBar` ,

May be you are referring code from the below blog post ...

http://iphonesdevsdk.blogspot.com/